# Where can ratpack-jackson version 1.1.1 be resolved?

Tags: ratpack

I have jcenter () included in my Gradle repositories using ratpack-gradle-1.1.1 plugin but 'compile ratpack.dependency ("Jackson")' results in unable to resolve dependency.  I have searched several repositories and have only located ratpack-jackson 0.9.9.  When I drop back from 1.1.1 to an older version my project throws exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ratpack has migrated the Jackson dependency into the core so you no longer need to specify the Jackson dependency explicitly.